# Blocking new devices on a network

Tags: networking

My university has implemented a strict new network policy, which we are generally told is "restricted unless permitted" whereas previously it was "permitted unless restricted".

For example, when we plug a new laptop into an ethernet port, it gets an IP address but can not ping out (either to named domains like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or numerical ones like 8.8.8.8). After asking the IT department for "permission", the network then permits the laptop to connect normally.

Most machines connected to the network via ethernet are Windows 10 ones where the IT staff have full administrative privileges over. A small percent are staff and student laptops which may have any operating system on it, and the IT staff do not have administrative privileges over them.

I'm just wondering how is this policy implemented? By a MAC address whitelist/blacklist? If so, where do these whitelists/blacklists reside? At the routers in each faculty building or in a central gateway? Out of curiosity I heard other people trying to spoof their MAC addresses to existing machines connected to the network (which were turned off for the experiment) but they still had the aforementioned network blocks applied to them. So there must be something more than MAC filters.

Disclaimer: I am not trying to circumvent network policy, I just want to learn how things are done.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

The ACL will most likely be held in a RADIUS server (most likely backed by a LDAP instance).

The actual control will probably be done at the Ethernet Switch.

The Ethernet Switch will change the vlan that the port is mapped to which will then only allow access to the captive portal which will direct you to IT support to get authorised.

I'd be very surprised if this was doing more than just MAC address filtering, but it might be associating a MAC address with a specific Ethernet port as well.